# Cocoalibspotify searching for specific song

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm trying to use the Spotify objective-c library to search for a specific song that belongs to an artist, album.  I don't want to use the searchWithSearchQuery method (which works ok) because I want to be more specific.  There is a method called searchWithURL shown below.  I don't see any documentation as to how to structure these URLs.  All it says is that it must start with spotify:search.  What comes after that? How do I specify a artist, album, song?  Thanks!

```
/** Creates a new SPSearch with the default page size from the given Spotify search URL. 

 This convenience method is simply returns a new, autoreleased SPSearch
 object. No caching is performed.

 @warning If you pass in an invalid search URL (i.e., any URL not
 starting `spotify:search:`, this method will return `nil`.

 @warning The search query will be sent to the Spotify search service
 immediately. Be sure you want to perform the search before creating the object!

 @param searchURL The search URL to create an SPSearch for.
 @param aSession The SPSession the track should exist in.
 @return Returns the created SPSearch object. 
 */
+(SPSearch *)searchWithURL:(NSURL *)searchURL inSession:(SPSession *)aSession;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search URLs are created by `SPSearch` instances after you create them, and they basically encode the query you passed the first time. So, `searchWithURL:` isn't going to be more useful to you than creating a search with a query.

However, to answer your wider question, you can use the [Spotify Advanced Search Syntax](http://web.archive.org/web/20120704131650/http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/) with `SPSearch` to do a more accurate search.

For example, to find tracks exactly named "Roar":

```
[SPSearch searchWithSearchQuery:@"track:Roar"
                      inSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];
```

To find tracks exactly named "Roar" by Katy Perry:

```
[SPSearch searchWithSearchQuery:@"track:Roar artist:\"Katy Perry\""
                      inSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];
```

...and so on. Check out the linked page for more details.

Comment: I actually have a follow up question if you'd be so kind.  I know you cannot use CocoaLibSpotify without a logged in user but is there any simple way to make a search without authenticating.  Maybe by directly calling http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=... using AFNetworking (which is used in our app).  I tried doing this but it returned a 400 even though pasting that URL in a browser works fine.

Comment: The web API is the way to go, but bear in mind that unauthenticated searches have a very high risk of returning results that won't be playable by the user once they log in due to catalog differences. I've called the search API many times using `NSURLRequest` and it works fine, so I'm not sure what AFNetworking is doing to break it. The body of the response should have a bit of info.

Comment: I figured it out.  Problem with the way I setup the request.  Thanks.